# My field Zip still stay unrequired in my customer form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, form-validation

I try to put a required-entry to my field "zip" but the `<label>` `<em>*</em>` still shows as `display:none`.

If someone can help me it would be great =)

```
<li class="fields">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text required-entry validate-zip <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

[image]

As you can see they are: `<em style="display:none;">*</em>`

and `<input [...] class="input-text validate-zip">`

even if i set `required-entry` in my code, the class `required-entry` is not apply

Comment: Can you update your question with a link to the page?

Comment: Hi, sorry i just forget to make this post as resolved.
I just resolved this in backoffice, System > Configuration > General > General
And just unselect my country for the optional Postal Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of **required** class use **required-entry**

Let me know if it is solved.

Comment: Hi, sorry i just forget to make this post as resolved.
I just resolved this in backoffice, System > Configuration > General > General
And just unselect my country for the optional Postal Code.

Answer (score 1):

From admin panel ->catalog->attributes->manage attributes  you can edit your  zip field properties   and set 'Values Required' to 'YES'

Comment: Sorry but it's a Customer Form. I don't see where is the match with "Catalog" and "Customer" . Manage attributes in Catalog from admin panel is only for products... not for customer